# Probability of union of disjoint events $[X=x \cap Y= z-x]$ for $x=0,1,...,z$ equals $\sum_{x=0}^z \mathbb{P}(X=x \cap Y=z-x)$

Tags: sum

Why can one write

$$\mathbb{P}([X=x \cap Y= z-x] \bigcup ... \bigcup [X=x+z \cap Y= z]) = \sum_{x=0}^z \mathbb{P}(X=x \cap Y=z-x)$$

?

Comment: This is an *axiom* of probability, so there's really nothing to show.  Maybe you should review the axioms--they are small in number and simple.

Comment: @whuber Yeah I recall it's an axiom. I think the question is more about the "intuition"/thinking behind it. E.g. what does it mean to take unions of events? And then the probability of that? And why equate that with summation?